# Pydrive example script problems

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Hello I´m getting this error with pydrive https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDrive , the json key is the same directory than script (a.py).

```
[XX@example.com user]# pip install PyDrive
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyDrive in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyDrive-1.0.0-py2.6.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): google-api-python-client>=1.2 in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from PyDrive)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyYAML>=3.0 in /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages (from PyDrive)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2>=0.8 in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from google-api-python-client>=1.2->PyDrive)
Cleaning up...
[XX@example.com user]# vi a.py
[XX@example.com user]# cat a.py
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
[XX@example.com user]# python a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PyDrive-1.0.0-py2.6.egg/pydrive/auth.py", line 14, in <module>
    from oauth2client.tools import ClientRedirectHandler
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/oauth2client/tools.py", line 27, in <module>
    import argparse
ImportError: No module named argparse
[XX@example.com user]#
```

---

Any idea about this?

Comment: what did you do after this error? did you solve it? what's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

argparse is not shipped with Python 2.6 (but is shipped with 2.7)

pip install argparse